# Merge the DES Helper into UWP?

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography, uwp

i'm using this method to encrypt/decrypt my data, but the windows universal app just do not support System.Security.Cryptography. So how can I just transplant these into UWP apps? thanks

```
    static string DES_Key = "lolhahaha";
    public static string DESEncrypt(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("sss");

            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data + timeStamp);

            des.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DES_Key);
            des.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DES_Key);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: DES, really? That has not been considered secure for over a decade. Don't use DES, use AES. AES is no harder to use, both are block based encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the windows universal app just do not support System.Security.Cryptography.

Why you said so? [Windows.Security.Cryptography namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx) is supported in UWP apps, you can use [CryptographicBuffer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.aspx) instead to encrypt and decrypt data.

Here in [SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.aspx) is code sample you may take a look. And you can find the supported algorithms in [SymmetricAlgorithmNames class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

You can now add .NET Core 1.0 NuGet packages to your project.json file to use System.Security.Cryptography classes. Note that old/obsolete algorithms are not available (DES).